# OOP : clone object to descendant class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Here is a OOP design/code question.
I wil try to simplify my problem to clarify.
I have a PecCollection class that represent a collection of Pec objects (*a Pec is a "Prise en charge", it's not very important to describe what is it. You can see it as any object a person should possess*).

Each Pec "belongs to" a Person, when and Person is created, it has his own PecCollection that list all of his Pecs. PecCollection is just a class storing an array of Pecs.
**The Pecs objects are created from data taken in the database.**

Person(0,1) --has-> PecCollection(1,n) --contains--> Pec

Now, I possibly (but maybe NOT) want to make a list of controls on each Pec and store datas about theses controls about each Pec (let's say "An amount of hours", *hoursNb*, for example).

What I could make is simply add a "nbHours" property on Pec Class, and store the nbHours given by the controle in that property.
But this, I think (maybe I'm wrong), isn't a good way of doing : it changes the responsability of the Pec Class (represent a basic Pec) to several responsabilities (represent a basic Pec AND and controled pec).
Moreover, not all the Pec will be controled.

I could make a ControledPec Class that inherits from Pec, with the nbHours property in addition. It seems to be a good solution.
ANd I could store theses objects in a ControlledPecCollection for each Person.

Person(0,1) --has--> PecCollection(1,n) --contains--> Pec<--is a-- ControlledPec

But there, here is my problem.
How can I create (AND : is it a good practice ?) the controledPecs objects from Pec Objects that already exists, without having to re-create controledPecs, by searching datas in the databse (as for Pec) ? Knowing that a ControledPec will always be a specialization of a Pec that already exists ?

I am in PHP.

Thank you i advance.

Comment: Are basic and controlled Pecs really that fundamentally different that they would warrant different classes? I'd say no. Whether a Pec is controlled or not should be determined by its state.

Comment: One way to achieve this is with Decorator Pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), but this seems to create way more complexity than just give a little more responsibility to some class. I'd go with El_Vanja solution.

Comment: It could be the good solution because in addition to the simplified example I gave, there are, for example, some calculated amount of datas from the PecCollection to  provide.
With the Decorator Pattern I could extands the class functionalities without modify the Class.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Felipe, Decorator seems to be the good solution here.